# AfterSumbit event in jqgrid not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

i am using jqgrid and here is script.

```
       var lastsel;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        // url: 'TestGrid/GridData',
        url: 'TestGrid/GridDataLoadOnce',
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['COM_NAME', 'COM_CODE', 'DELV_UNITS', 'LOT_SIZE', 'TICK_SIZE', 'TICK_VALUE'],
        PostData: { "id": "4" },
        colModel: [
        { name: 'COM_NAME', index: 'COM_NAME', width: 90, editable: true },
        { name: 'COM_CODE', index: 'COM_CODE', width: 100, editable: true },
        { name: 'DELV_UNITS', index: 'DELV_UNITS', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'LOT_SIZE', index: 'LOT_SIZE', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'TICK_SIZE', index: 'TICK_SIZE', width: 80, align: "right", editable: true },
        { name: 'TICK_VALUE', index: 'TICK_VALUE', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true }
    ],
        // multiselect:false, // select multiple rows
        //rowNum: 50,
        //pgbuttons : true,
        //rowTotal: 2000,
        //  rowList: [20, 30, 50], // number of records show
        rowList: ReturnRowList(),
        //         /* Event Trigger after every database hit */
        //        loadComplete: function (data) {
        //          alert(jQuery.stringify(data));
        //      },




        //rowList: "rowList" ,
        loadonce: true, // hit only once on the server
        //  mtype: "GET",
        rownumbers: true, // show the numbers on rows
        rownumWidth: 40, // row number's column width
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#pager',
        sortname: 'COM_NAME',
        viewrecords: true, // show the total records on the end of the page
        jsonReader: {
            page: "page",
            total: "total"
        }, // url to be called on edit
        editurl: "TestGrid/EditRecord",
        mytype: "POST",
        caption: "JSON Example"
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { del: true, add: false, edit: true, save: false, cancel: false, cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel" }, {reloadAfteSubmit:true, closeAfterDelete: true, closeAfterEdit: true },
    {
     afterSubmit: function (response) {
            // you should return from server OK in sucess, any other message on error
            alert("after Submit");
            if (response.responseText == true) {
                alert("Update is succefully")
                return [true, "", ""]
            }
            else {
                alert("Update failed")
                return [false, "", ""]
            }
        },
    }



    );
});
```

when i click on the edit button a pop appears , after making changes when i click on the save button i want confiramtion on client side either record is insert properly or not. for this i am using afterSubmit event which is not firing . please tell me what can be the possible issue ?

Comment: where is afterSubmit event? i haven't found in your code

Comment: sorry i updated my question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not place different parts of your JavaScript code which uses jqGrid in different `$(document).ready(...)` event handler. Different handler can be in general executed in different order. On the other side you can't call `navGrid` before jqGrid is created and you can't call `inlineNav` before jqGrid is created and before navigator bar will be created by `navGrid`. So you should place all the calls inside of **one ready-event handler**.

Now about your main question. Your current code contains many typing errors. jqGrid will use only option which it know and will ignore all unknown or typed in a wrong way options. For example you use `afterEdit` callback, but mean probably [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events). Even in the title of the question you write about `AfterSumbit` and mean `afterSumbit`. Moreover you specify such callback for Add and not for Edit button.

You use many wrong names in other places. For example `mytype: "POST"` instead of `mtype: "POST"`. `PostData: { "id": "4" }` instead of `postData: { "id": "4" }` and so on. All wrong written options will be just ignored by jqGrid and default values are used instead.

**UPDATED**: Correct way would be to examine exactly the documentation. You will find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) the description of parameters of `navGrid`:

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", parametersOfNavGrid,
    parametersOfEdit, parametersOfAdd, parametersOfDel,
    parametersOfSearch, parametersOfView);
```

Every from parametersOfXXX parameters are optional and should be an object. The options of `navGrid` (inclusive default values) are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters)

If you use `navGrid` to add only Edit, Delete, Search and Reload buttons then you can use

```
{ add: false }
```

instead of

```
{ del: true, add: false, edit: true, save: false, cancel: false, cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel" }
```

because `del: true` and `edit: true` properties are default and all other properties not exist in `navGrid`.

`navGrid` creates navigator bar with buttons. If the user clicks on one from the buttons then it calls `editGridRow`, `delGridRow`, `searchGrid` or `viewGridRow` method of [the form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing). The options `parametersOfEdit`, `parametersOfAdd`, `parametersOfDel`, `parametersOfSearch`, `parametersOfView` allows you to specify the options of the corresponding methods.

You used

```
{ reloadAfteSubmit:true, closeAfterDelete: true, closeAfterEdit: true }
```

so probably you want that jqGrid calls `editGridRow` with `reloadAfteSubmit: true` and `closeAfterEdit: true` options and it calls `delGridRow` with `closeAfterDelete: true` option. The defalult value of `reloadAfterSubmit` (not `reloadAfteSubmit` which you use) is already `true` for edit and delete. `closeAfterDelete` option not exist at all (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2)) and jqGrid close Delete form and reload the grid after Delete automatically. So the usage of `navGrid` could look like below

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { add: false },
    { //the Edit options
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmit: function (response) {
        // you should return from server OK in sucess, any other message on error
        alert("after Submit");
        if (response.responseText == true) {
            alert("Update is succefully")
            return [true, "", ""]
        }
        else {
            alert("Update failed")
            return [false, "", ""]
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i got your point . now what can i do ? i want to inform user either record is edited properly or not ? is there any event for edit ?

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui: You are welcome! I updated my answer (see **UPDATED** part).

Comment: one more thing ? now the event properly occurs but the form is not closing when edit failed ?

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui: it's so by design. If the user types fill the form and makes **an error in some field** for example then the user have chance to fix the problem without discarding **all the changes** by closing the form.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find **afterSubmit Event** in your code. It should be like this

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { del: true, add: false, edit: true, save: false, cancel: false, cancelicon: "ui-icon-cancel" }, {reloadAfteSubmit:true, closeAfterDelete: true, closeAfterEdit: true },
    {     
     afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
        //Check the response 
        if(response.responseText != ""){
          //for successfull editing return true.
                return [true,"Success"]; //  return [success,message,new_id] 
            }else{
                return [false,"Error"];
            }
     }
```

Comment: i changed my code and after submit event is working after i add new row  but not after i edit any row. my problem is is there any event which would occur after editing any row in grid ?

Comment: i couldn't understand your problem.. what error you recieve when you edit a row?

Comment: the problem is when you add new row afterSubmit event occurs . but when you edit any existing row which event occurs ? there should be some event after editing any row ?

Comment: try beforeShowForm event to check whether you are on the right method. i tried with your code it shows errors. i dont know what save icon in you navgrid means